# Schedule PHP task running in IIS

Tags: php, iis, scheduled-tasks

Does anyone have a simple solution for scheduling PHP tasks running in IIS?

I have a php script which backs up our databases and emails to our backup address on a separate server.

I have admin access to the server. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not aware of a scheduling function in IIS, but what about Windows's task planner?

Comment: hmm maybe this should be posted on server fault group? im not sure :-s

Comment: ah windows task planner sounds good, but I cant exactly have it load internet explorer, it would leave multiple windows open?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that you can run PHP from the command line, just set these jobs using the Windows Task Scheduler, they can be configured from Control Panel/Scheduled Tasks.

A typical task might look something like:

```
C:\PHP\php.exe -f BOINCStats.php
```

with the "Start in" directory set as

```
C:\PHP
```

You can find full details for running PHP from the command line in the [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.php)

**EDIT**

If you create a .bat file, you might like to ensure that it references a specific php.ini

e.g.

```
C:\xampp\php\php -c \xampp\php\php5CLI.ini %1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9
```

Comment: Did you mean php.exe? I can't see php.bat

Comment: So I create a batch file with this .. C:\PHP5\php.exe -f "C:\PHP Scripts\script.php"

Comment: I will accept this answer, but I have to wait 7 minutes first.

Comment: I have changed this to php.exe... I actually have a bat file that sets a few configuration switches common to all the files I run from the scheduler, and I just cut-and-pasted that example tasks from an actual scheduled PHP task; but you could just as easily call the php.exe directly

Comment: Got it all setup for daily backups. Tested the scheduled task and boom emails with my database backups came through. Many thanks :)